# Get previous work week dates in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to get the previous work week dates (Mon-Fri) in BigQuery. 
So far I've managed the following:

```
SELECT 
DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(MONDAY)) as previous_mon,
DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(MONDAY)), INTERVAL 4 DAY) as previous_fri
```

But this gives me the most recent Monday-Friday dates, which is actually this week. In other words, if I run this query today (28-06-2019), I get these results:

```
Row today         previous_mon    previous_fri  
1   2019-06-28    2019-06-24      2019-06-28
```

But what I actually need is:

```
Row today         previous_mon    previous_fri  
1   2019-06-28    2019-06-17      2019-06-21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subtract another week:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(MONDAY)), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) as previous_mon,
       DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(MONDAY)), INTERVAL 4 DAY), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) as previous_fri
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CURRENT_DATE() today,
  DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(MONDAY)), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) previous_mon,
  DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(MONDAY)), INTERVAL 3 DAY) previous_fri
```

with result

```
Row today       previous_mon    previous_fri     
1   2019-06-28  2019-06-17      2019-06-21
```